# Size of list exceeded and I am losing elements when calling ToList() in C#, LINQ

Tags: c#, list, linq

I am reading from a file. The var contains about 512 objects. When I am using ToList() I am only getting 438. That is basically the default size for a list. I have tried to increase it to 512 and it has worked, but when I am calling ToList() I am getting again 438. If anybody can help me with that. IF i break in the if and get to print for example 200 Objects I get the first objects who do not appear when I am not breaking. I am losing records because of the default size.

Is there any way of changing that when calling ToList()?

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");

        var var = from elem in doc.Descendants("Groups").Elements()
                  select new Group
                  {
                      x1 = elem.Element("x1") != null ? elem.Element("x1").Value : String.Empty,
                      x2 = elem.Element("x2") != null ? elem.Element("x2").Value : String.Empty,
                      x3 = elem.Element("x3") != null ? elem.Element("x3").Value : String.Empty,
                      x4 = elem.Element("x4") != null ? elem.Element("x4").Value : String.Empty,
                      x5 = elem.Element("x5") != null ? elem.Element("x5").Value : String.Empty,
                      x6 = elem.Element("x6") != null ? elem.Element("x6").Value : String.Empty,
                      x7 = elem.Element("x7") != null ? elem.Element("x7").Value : String.Empty
                  };
        int size = var.ToList().Capacity;
        Console.WriteLine(size);

        List<Group> list = new List<Group>(size);



        list = var.ToList();


        int i = 0;
        foreach (Group ins in list)
        {
            i++;
            Console.WriteLine(ins.ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Comment: `List` capacity isn't a hard limit, it will effectively grow until you run out of RAM. There's something else wrong with your code.

Comment: Why use `Capacity` instead of `Count`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] (including the XML).

Comment: first of all change the name of `var`, and make it realistic like data or something else.

Comment: If i am using count I get 438 as well, if I am using capacity i get 512. The thing that seems to be the problem is that i have for example 500 records and when I iterate through the list and print I only get the last 438, so basically I am losing the first 62 records. When I am printing and selecting to print for example the first 200 (if i == 200) break;, I get the first 62 records and the next till 200.

Comment: You are saying you have 512 records, but this is based on `Capacity` which has (almost) nothing to do with the number of items that are actually in the list. Please don't rely on that value for anything since it's an implementation detail.

Comment: I'll bet that your file actually has 438 items in it. 512 is the next power of 2 bigger than that number, and will likely represent the Capacity of the list, i.e. how big the list can get before it has to resize itself. (... too slow at typing!)

Comment: What is the value of `doc.Descendants("Groups").Elements().Count()`?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to using `Capacity` instead of `Count` to retrieve the number of items in `var`:

```
int size = var.ToList().Capacity;
```

This is most likely wrong (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2(v=vs.110).aspx)):

> Capacity is the number of elements that the List can store before resizing is required, whereas Count is the number of elements that are actually in the List.